# checking do while loop

Tags: java, boolean, do-while

I have created an `ArrayList` of users. I have made a method to add new users. The users must have an email and the program has to check the `ArrayList` to see if the user already exists in the `ArrayList`. If I run the check for a correct email and correct name separately, it works, but when I combine it using this `while(userExists || matchFound)`, it doesn't work. I have tried everything, so hope you can help me. Thanks in advance.

```
public void addUser()
{
    System.out.println("-----------------------------"); //separation of previous screen
    System.out.println("Create a new user.");

    boolean userExists = false;
    boolean matchFound = false;

    String userToAdd;

    do {
        System.out.println("Username: ");
        userToAdd = input.next();
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".+@.+\\.[a-z]+");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(userToAdd);
        matchFound = m.matches();

        if (matchFound) {
            System.out.println("just a check if it is a email");
        }
        if(!matchFound) {
            System.out.println("no email. Try again.");
            matchFound = true;
        }
        for(User currentUser : db.getUsers()) {
            if (currentUser.getName().equals(userToAdd)) {
                System.out.println("User already exist. Try again.");
                userExists = true;
            }
        }

    } while(userExists || matchFound);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your code would work better if you got the naming right. "matchFound" is not really telling and I guess that is where much of the confusion comes from. This is why I suggest you use "isEmail" instead. This makes the code much more readable. Another problem is that you're using variables inside the loop that you initialize only once outside of the loop. This works well for the first iteratation of the loop but leads to uncertain behaviour the second time. For example if you're entering an email that is already in the system, `userExists` would be set to true and stay true for consecutive iterations of the loop.

I also removed the output for the case where the email is valid. The user experience is better if you just present errors in the case where they occur. You're surely going to present the user with further functionality after they have entered a valid username. This will be enough feedback so that the user understands that the operation was successful.

This should work:

```
public void addUser()
{
    System.out.println("-----------------------------"); //separation of previous screen
    System.out.println("Create a new user.");

    boolean userExists = false;
    boolean isEmail = false;

    do
    {
        userExists = false;
        isEmail = false;

        System.out.print("Username: ");
        String userToAdd = input.next();

        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".+@.+\\.[a-z]+");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(userToAdd);
        isEmail = m.matches();

        if (!isEmail) 
        {
            System.out.println("Not an email. Try again.");
        }
        for(User currentUser : db.getUsers()) 
        {
            if (currentUser.getName().equals(userToAdd)) 
            {
                System.out.println("User already exist. Try again.");
                userExists = true;
                break;
            }
        }

    }while(userExists || !isEmail);
}
```

Comment: this is answer has been flagged as low quality answer. please add some explanation to your answer.

Comment: Had to initialize the boolean outside the do so the while could recognize it. The set the userExists and isEmail as you did to false. Then it worked. Thank you so much for the help

Answer (score 1):

You want to stay in the loop as long as the user is not a valid email or it already exists. Therefore you need :

```
while(userExists || !matchFound);
```

and you probably shouldn't set matchFound to true when it's false :

```
if(!matchFound){
    System.out.println("no email. Try again.");
    matchFound = true; // remove this line
}
```

It should only be set by `matchFound = m.matches();`

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to stay unless and until the user name does not exist and has valid email id. You should do the following:

```
while(!userExists || !matchFound);
```

With this you will loop until and unless you have both valid data.

Answer (score 0):

1. you should not set `matchfound` to false when it is false. other wise in the next loop it will be true by default. and you did not change it to false in your first block.
2. then you should use `!matchfound` instead match found. so that when you didn't found a match you will loop again

Answer (score 0):

You might want to reintialize the booleans to `false` as the first statements inside the do loop.  Otherwise, if `userExists` is assigned `true` for an iteration, it will stay `true` for all the successive iterations.

```
do
{
   userExists = false;
   matchFound = false;
   System.out.println("Username: ");
   userToAdd = input.next();


}
```